# Retirement accounts - limits on asset contributions

Tags: united-states, taxes, 401k, ira, retirement

If someone has appreciated assets like shares or equity of a privately held company and they want to transfer those into a tax-deferred retirement account like an IRA or 401k, is that possible?

If so, how does that work with the annual contribution limits? Are the limits calculated on the basis or on the current FMV?

Comment: You might be interested in [What's Really Going on With Mitt Romney's $102 Million IRA](https://www.theatlantic.com/politics/archive/2012/09/whats-really-going-on-with-mitt-romneys-102-million-ira/261500/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding 401K (Roth, Regular, or Post-tax) can only be funded though your payroll.

Now onto the IRA, a good document is [IRS Publication 590-A Contributions 
to Individual Retirement Arrangements (IRAs)](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/p590a.pdf). it includes several times that contributions must be in cash:

> **Individual Retirement Account**
>
> An individual retirement account is a
>   trust or custodial ac- count set up in the United States for the
>   exclusive benefit  of you or your beneficiaries. The account is
>   created by a  written document. The document must show that the ac-
>   count meets all of the following requirements.
>
> - The trustee or
>     custodian must be a bank, a federally  insured credit union, a savings
>     and loan association,  or an entity approved by the IRS to act as
>     trustee or  custodian.
> - The trustee or custodian generally cannot
>     accept con- tributions of more than the deductible amount for the 
>     year. However, rollover contributions and employer  contributions to a
>     simplified employee pension (SEP)  can be more than this amount.
> - Contributions, except for rollover contributions, must  be in cash.
>     See  Rollovers , later

...

> **When Can Contributions Be Made?**
>
> As  soon  as  you  open  your 
>   traditional  IRA,  contributions  can be made to it through your
>   chosen sponsor (trustee or  other administrator). Contributions must
>   be in the form of  money (cash, check, or money order). Property
>   cannot be  contributed.
>
> Although property cannot be contributed, your
>   IRA may  invest in certain property.

But what about Roth IRA?

> **What Is a Roth IRA?**
>
> A Roth IRA is an individual retirement plan that,
>   except as  explained in this chapter, is subject to the rules that
>   apply  to a  traditional IRA  (defined next). It can be either an ac-
>   count  or  an  annuity.  Individual  retirement  accounts   and 
>   annuities   are  described  in  chapter  1  under  How  Can  a 
>   Traditional IRA Be Opened?

the rest of that section have to do with can you contribute, how to convert an IRA to a Roth IRA

Non-cash items can be purchased and held by the IRA, they can be rolled over into an IRA, and they distributed, but all contributions must be in cash.

Comment: Good citation of "Contributions must be in the form of
money (cash, check, or money order)."

Answer (score 2):

It sure would be nice if the $5K I invested in AAPL in 1981 could be moved to an IRA while only paying tax on $5,000 instead of the $855K that it's currently worth... but no.  An action like this rebases the money, and you could only transfer $5500 (or $6500) of the current value into the IRA<sup>1</sup>, and would first have to pay taxes on it.

As far as a 401(k), you couldn't do it anyway, since that's only for earned income from your employer.

<sup>1</sup> Ignoring the fact that deductibility phases out at a certain income level (based on your income and filing status).

Comment: Does it matter whether it's a Roth or traditional IRA?

Comment: @g491.  No.  (I'd love to be proven wrong, though.)